# How can I add value's into existing JSON?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, http

I have below JSON

```
{Name = \""john kk\"", Ownership = \"Private\", Phone = \"9999999999\", Active = \"Yes\" }
```

Here I want to insert value from C# request object for the key's
ie. Name, Phone 
and then have to send in service call.
How can I insert values into existing json

i have below code :
 public AccountResponse SetSalseforceAccounts(AccountRequest request)
    {
      return ServiceCall(
      request,
      "Request Completed successfully",
      "Unable to complete request",
      null,
      null,
      (AccountResponse response) =>
      {
        //string AccountId = fetch salesforce AccountId from core.Account table and pass for updation and deletion.

```
    SalesForceService.SalesForceServiceClient salesFroceServiceClient = new SalesForceService.SalesForceServiceClient();
    SalesForceService.SalesForceRequest salesForceReq = new SalesForceService.SalesForceRequest();
    using (new OperationContextScope(salesFroceServiceClient.InnerChannel))
    {
      try
      {

        string data = String.Format("{\"Name\":\"{0}\", \"Ownership\":\"1005555\", \"Phone\":\"545454545\", \"Active__c\":\"{1}\"}", request.Entity.ShortName, request.Entity.Active ? "Yes" : "No");
        salesForceReq.Data = data;
        if (request.Action == RequestActions.Create)
        {
          //response.SalesForceResponce = salesFroceServiceClient.CreateSalesForceAccount(accountData);
          //SalesForceService.SalesForceResponse result = salesFroceServiceClient.CreateSalesForceAccount(accountData);
        }
        else if (request.Action == RequestActions.Update)
        {
          //SalesForceService.SalesForceResponse 
          SalesForceService.SalesForceResponse result = salesFroceServiceClient.CreateSalesForceAccount(salesForceReq);
          //salesFroceServiceClient.UpdateSalesForceAccount();
        }
        else if (request.Action == RequestActions.Delete)
        {
          //salesFroceServiceClient.UpdateSalesForceAccount();
        }            
      }
      finally
      {
        salesFroceServiceClient.Close();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: basically i have to fill values into already generated JSON dynamically.

Comment: Can you add your C# Code so we can see what your trying to achieve?

Comment: it does not match the [JSON](http://json.org/) standard.